# How to remove a set a string within a string followed by n more words in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Example: I have a string,

```
> myString <- c(“Regal bar Opp New Market Esplanade”, “Netaji Indoor Stadium, Opp Eden Gardens, Kolkata”)
```

I am required to remove the word “Opp” and the next two words following “Opp” from the entire string, that is I am looking for the following output:

[1] “Regal bar Esplanade”   “Netaji Indoor Stadium, Kolkata”

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Just do lapply

```
myString <- c(“Regal bar Opp New Market Esplanade”, 
              “Netaji Indoor Stadium, Opp Eden Gardens, Kolkata”)
lapply(strsplit(myString, split = " "), 
       function(x) x[-c(match("Opp", x), 
                        match("Opp", x)+1, 
                        match("Opp", x)+2)])
```

or do sapply directly to get the format you had from the start

```
sapply(strsplit(myString, split = " "), 
       function(x) paste(x[-c(match("Opp", x), 
                              match("Opp", x)+1, 
                              match("Opp", x)+2)], 
                         collapse = " "))
# [1] "Regal bar Esplanade"            "Netaji Indoor Stadium, Kolkata"
```

Cheers,
Mike